# Can't playback at 60 FPS

Tags: rendering, armature

I have AMD Rayzen 5, Zotac RTX 2060, 2X8 GB DDR4 - 3200 and 500GB SSD. How do I optimize it to run the playback at 60FPS? Or is the system not powerful enough?